# Replacing Java Awt deprecated method

Tags: java, event-handling, awt, mouseevent, deprecated

I have found a really old code which has a deprecated java method.How do i convert into new method.

```
public boolean mouseDown(Event e, int x, int y) 
{
//code
}
```

Comment: http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/doc/java/tutorial/post1.0/converting/convertingAWT.html#events

Comment: Consider using a `MouseListener` instead

Answer (score 1):

So the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#mouseDown(java.awt.Event,%20int,%20int)) state

> **Deprecated.** As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by processMouseEvent(MouseEvent).

If we look at the [documentation for `processMouseEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#processMouseEvent-java.awt.event.MouseEvent-) it states

> Processes mouse events occurring on this component by dispatching them
>   to any registered `MouseListener` objects. This method is not called
>   unless mouse events are enabled for this component. Mouse events are
>   enabled when one of the following occurs:
>
> A `MouseListener` object is registered via `addMouseListener`. Mouse
>   events are enabled via enableEvents.

So, the answer would seem to be, use a `MouseListener`. See [How to write a mouse listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more details

Comment: I would be grateful if you please link the documentation of the mouseDown.

Comment: I did, it's on the first line.  Of course you could also google "java docs component"

Comment: Why is the return type boolean instead of void?

Comment: @prithviparre For what?

Comment: public boolean mouseDown(Event e , int x,int y)

Comment: I would assume its used to determine if the event should be propagated out not (ie consumed)